# Python: weirdness with queue processing in a thread in a process

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a curious case of queue processing with python. Let me describe it first:

1. Main thread creates a global object that is responsible for collecting and processing messages (the object has a queue inside)
2. That global object has a method that is started in a thread. Method has access to the queue (which belongs to the object) and reads messages from it
3. Main thread starts a bunch of processes (with multiprocessing.Process) which publish messages to the global object.

Problem is: for queue processor the queue is always empty. Let me illustrate the problem with some code:

```
import threading as t
import time
import sys
from multiprocessing import Process
if sys.version_info.major is 2:
    import Queue as queue
else:
    import queue

class ExampleRecorder:
    queue = queue.Queue()

    def run(self):
        self.thread = t.Thread(target=self.start_processor)
        self.thread.daemon = True
        self.thread.start()

    def start_processor(self):
        while 1:
            print("PROCESSOR! QUEUE ID: {}. QUEUE SIZE: {}. IS EMPTY: {}".format(id(self.queue), self.queue.qsize(), self.queue.empty()))
            time.sleep(1)

    def push_message(self, span):
        self.queue.put(span)
        print("RECORDER! QUEUE ID: {}. QUEUE SIZE: {}".format(id(self.queue), self.queue.qsize()))

er = ExampleRecorder()
er.run()

def producer():
    while 1:
        print("Adding an item")
        er.push_message("foo")
        time.sleep(1)


proc = Process(target=producer)
proc.start()
```

Sample output of the script would be:

```
$ python3 model.py
PROCESSOR! QUEUE ID: <queue.Queue object at 0x1095f9b70>. QUEUE SIZE: 0. IS EMPTY: True
Adding an item
RECORDER! QUEUE ID: <queue.Queue object at 0x1095f9b70>. QUEUE SIZE: 1
PROCESSOR! QUEUE ID: <queue.Queue object at 0x1095f9b70>. QUEUE SIZE: 0. IS EMPTY: True
Adding an item
RECORDER! QUEUE ID: <queue.Queue object at 0x1095f9b70>. QUEUE SIZE: 2
PROCESSOR! QUEUE ID: <queue.Queue object at 0x1095f9b70>. QUEUE SIZE: 0. IS EMPTY: True
```

As you can see, a queue receives objects and grows, but for processor it's always empty. What could possibly go wrong there? Is there something tricky about processing of a shared queue in-a-thread-in-a-process?

P.S. Checked with Python 2.7.12 and 3.5.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Queue.Queue` only works in the same process, it's used with threads, not with separate processes.

You'll need a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance to do inter-process communication, but you'll also have to restructure the code to pass explicitly the instance of the queue to the `producer`. As it is now, each producer will have a different instance created when the `ExampleRecorder` definition is evaluated in the new process.

**Note:** With the code you wrote, *all `ExampleRecorder` instances (**in the same process**) share the same queue*! Are you sure this is what you wanted?

By defining `queue` inside the `class ...` block, `queue` is an attribute of **the class, NOT its instances**. This is very different from defining `queue` in `__init__()`. with a simpler example:

```
from queue import Queue

class SampleClass:
  queue = Queue()

class AnotherSample:
  def __init__(self):
    self.queue = Queue()

inst1 = SampleClass()
inst2 = SampleClass()

inst3 = AnotherSample()
inst4 = AnotherSample()
```

If we test the `queue` attributes, we see the difference: (the `is` operator tests whether two variables are alias for the same object)

```
inst1.queue is inst2.queue
Out[8]: True

inst3.queue is inst4.queue
Out[9]: False
```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed description!